# Using React Redux Toolkit I can't figure out the correct Typescript syntax for defining a thunk function returning a value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-thunk

I'm using typescript in a React Redux Toolkit project. Creating an Async Thunk action function that should return a boolean I got stuck trying to devise the correct Typescript syntax for it:

```
export const isAccountRemovable = (accountId: AccountId): AppThunk<boolean> => { 
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    return false;
  };
};
```

This gives me an error on the returning type of the inner function:

> Type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{ books: BooksState; accounts: AccountsState; transactions: TransactionsState; }, unknown, AnyAction>, getState: () => { ...; }) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'AppThunk'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

If I try to specify a return type for the inner function:

```
export const isAccountRemovable = (accountId: AccountId): AppThunk<boolean> => { 
  return async (dispatch, getState): boolean => {
    return false;
  };
};
```

Then the error is:

> The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type. Did you mean to write 'Promise'?ts(1064)

Ok, lets then do the following:

```
export const isAccountRemovable = (accountId: AccountId): AppThunk<boolean> => { 
  return async (dispatch, getState): Promise<boolean> => {
    return false;
  };
};
```

But this gives me an error anyway:

> Type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{ books: BooksState; accounts: AccountsState; transactions: TransactionsState; }, unknown, AnyAction>, getState: () => { ...; }) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'AppThunk'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: How about ` AppThunk<Promise<boolean>>`?

Comment: Yes! You are right. Fool of me. I didn't realize the fact that the inner function is async is screaming that it expects a promise as response. I even tried turning the inner function sync then I can use "AppThunk<boolean>"... Please, move your comments to the answer to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below.

```
export const isAccountRemovable = (accountId: AccountId): AppThunk<Promise<boolean>> => { 
  return async (dispatch, getState): Promise<boolean> => {
    return false;
  };
};
```

*I have moved my comment to this answer space.